# Each row editable using ui-grid AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ng-grid, ui-grid

I need to make row editable instead of each field/column. I am also following the tutorial for [tutorial for row edit feature](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/205_row_editable)

Please find the plnkr link also where I am trying to make row editable instead of each column. I have the button on each row but it doesn't have any functioning.

[plnkr link](http://plnkr.co/edit/4FuwUdARsyu2w1kL4QDk?p=preview)

```
  $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = [
    { name: 'id'},
    { name: 'age'  },
    {name: " Edit" , cellTemplate:'<button class=\"btn btn-xs btn-primary\" ng-click=\"grid.appScope.openModal(grid, row)\"> <i class="fa fa-edit" ></i></button>' }];
```

Comment: I need to edit full row. I tried to implement by reading the tutorial for ag-grid but were unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'cellEditableCondition' option on each field and then put one variable to change the status of the fields.

```
  $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = [
{ name: 'id'},
{ name: 'age', edicellEditableCondition : variable (true or false) }...]
```

And then you can change all rows only with one.
Hope it helps.